# Auto delete messages in the specified channel by time? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I did an **automatic-channel** cleaning at the **time** I needed `(Monday 15:00)`

But my program does not work as it should.
The countdown starts when a message appears in the channel.

I need the channel to be cleared without new messages in **channel.id**

**CODE**

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (client.channels.cache.get("829042005236645900")) {

    const job = schedule.scheduleJob('30 * * * * *', function () {
      console.log('Delete');
      message.channel.bulkDelete(20)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You could start the countdown / timer in the `client.on('ready') event`. As long as you have it in the `message event`, it will also be restarted with each new message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating the schedule inside the event handler, and that may be what's causing the issue. Here's an alternative to that:

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("829042005236645900");
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('30 * * * * *', function () {
  console.log('Delete');
  channel.bulkDelete(20);
});
```

However, it also looks like you want to make the event fire every 30 seconds? `node-schedule` has a system for that called [Recurrence Rule Scheduling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#user-content-recurrence-rule-scheduling):

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("829042005236645900");
const job = new schedule.scheduleJob({ second: new schedule.Range(0, 59, 30) },
  function () {
    console.log('Delete');
    channel.bulkDelete(20);
});
```